# Geodesic balls in warped product spaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $g_S$ be a Riemannian metric on the $n$-dimensional sphere $S^{n}$ and consider the space $M=(0,a)\times S^{n}$ with the warped metric 
$g=dt^2+f(t)^2g_S$, where $f\colon [0,a)\to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function such that 
$$
f(0)=0\,,\quad f(t) >0\quad t\in (0,a)\,.
$$
I would like to understand which are the assumptions on $f$ in order to add a point $O$ to $M$ such that the geodesic balls centered at $O$ are the slices $\{t\}\times S^{n}$.

This fact occurs for instance if $M$ is a space form and $O$ is the origin.

Comment: Are you requiring that $M\cup\{O\}$ have a smooth structure such that $g$ is smooth at $O$?

Comment: Yes, I require that. My goal is to have a suitable generalization of space forms.

Comment: Smoothness at $O$ is the only restriction, right? If I understand notation correctly, for any metric of this kind the shortest path from the origin to a point is a ray (proof is the same as in proving that line segments are shortest paths in Euclidean space). Thus the function $f$ does not matter so much, except for its behavior near $0$. Unless you provide more information about what you expect your 'generalized space form' to look like, I don't think it is possible to give a good answer.